# PathFinding in geoMapNav Geolocation Toolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, mapquest

**Hi 
I am using geomapnav 1.0 in my app in 3dunity 
I want to add pathfinding in mapquest in my app
how i do that??

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13153

Answer (score 0):

You can use A* Path Finder it is very accurate in terms of AI and there is customizable bot speed too.

Check [this](http://arongranberg.com/astar/) and implement it.